# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion, promotion, top-7

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Answer (score 1):

**elevator pitch**

> Just because it runs in a browser doesn't mean it can't be awesome.

**tagline/motto**

> Desktop apps? So last year.

Comment: +1 - These seem to work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

#### Tagline

Problem with a web app? Solved.

Comment: We're already getting too many questions about websites that aren't web apps. We need to make the distinction.

Comment: Broken up to make it easier to work out what to vote on. Others are free to scavenge anything salvageable from the first version.

Answer (score 0):

**elevator pitch**

> Got a question about a web application?  This is the place to get an answer.

**tagline/motto**

> If it's on the web, ask about it here.

Answer (score -1):

**nothingtoinstall:** The Community Driven Web Manual

Comment: as long as people don't get the mis-conception that this is a web-manual about html or javscript.