# Add a few-word description to the masthead

Tags: feature-request, design

There are quite a few people (including myself, until now) asking questions related to programming, rather than using, web apps.

Could you add some text to the masthead informing people, in just a few words of subtitle, that this is a site for asking questions about /using/ web apps?

Comment: Related: [Questions off-topic because they are about developing web applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2519/88163), [Web Applications isn't for bad questions about app development and Super User either](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4691/88163),[Where can I ask a question about one of the phases of the development lifecycle of web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685/88163)

Answer (score 1):

That's all part of designing the site while it is still in beta:

[Write and Elevator Pitch/Tagline](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/709/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)