# Questions off-topic because they are about developing web applications

Tags: support, vote-to-close, flagging

Several times each day (usually) I see questions that are about developing web applications, which are off-topic, e.g. [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51601/control-states-are-getting-wash-off-while-moving-between-pages).

I always flag the question (*Flagging* -> *The question doesn't belong here because it is ...* -> *off-topic because ...* -> *It is a question about creating/developing a web application*), and leave a comment with a boiler-plate text like *This site is for questions about USING web applications, not developing them. You should move your question to e.g. stackoverflow.com*.

It is not much work per question, but given the high volume of these questions, I find myself spending a lot of time flagging and commenting on them.

Is there an easier, or more recommended way, of dealing with these? Could this process be automated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automating flagging is something which you're almost never likely to see. If you feel that you're posting the same comment over & again - [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) gives a popup with 6 configurable auto-comments, which you can easily click to insert.

Reconfigure  the comments to your most used boilerplate ones & you could save some hassle of retyping them over & again

<sub><sub>I swear there was a userscript to reduce the clicks required for flagging/closing - making it almost 1 click, but I can't seem to find it. Or can I? ;)</sub></sub>

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I had in mind.