# Web Applications isn't for bad questions about app development and Super User either

Tags: discussion, questions, migration, vote-to-close

Hopefully this will reach the eyes of one of ours community members that are voting to migrate to Super User "bad" questions about programming / developing apps.

Recent cases

- [Warning: Angular 6+ Circular Dependency Detected](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/133257/88163)
- [how to refresh a fragment in BottomNavigation bar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/133265/88163)

While it could be arguable if the topics of the above questions are on-topic on Super User they don't include a brief description of the search/research efforts as is suggested on the standard guidelines for asking questions on any site of the Stack Exchange network, so instead of voting to migrate, please vote to close as a question for creating/developing a web application, otherwise it's very likely that they will be rejected and we should start over.

References

- [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/289691)
- [What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/289691)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have now been closed and the misunderstanding was resolved.