# Web Applications "elevator pitch" (site description ) in Tour

Tags: discussion, tour

Because participation here is very low, I have jumped directly to edit the "elevator pitch" (site description) depicted in the [Web Applications Tour](https://https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) instead of making [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as this is something very easily reverted in case that it be really necessary. The changes were

1. Removed *power users*.
2. Replace *any questions* with *questions about the usage of web applications*.
3. Expanded the wording pointing to the detailed version of the meta post working as the table of contents about the site scope.

> **Welcome to Web Applications**, a platform devoted to resolving all your inquiries about web applications. Our Q&A network, Stack Exchange, comprises individuals like you who contribute to this platform. Our goal is to compile a thorough database of information by collecting detailed answers to all questions regarding the usage of web applications.
>
> We understand that the topic of "web applications" can be extensive and intricate. That's why we have spent more than a decade narrowing down our area of expertise. For more information, please check out [What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/). Here is a brief overview of our approach, which we encourage you to read carefully.

The above was done based on the answers to

- [Let's make "research efforts" more specific: request to search the web app help](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4893/88163)
- [As of today, May 2023, who do we understand that is our intended audience and what is the first that we tell them about how to participate?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5012/88163)
- [A better name for this community, part 1](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5035/88163)

Regarding [A better name for this community, part 1](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5035/88163), we have not yet received enough contributions to move into part 2, which might be to make a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to ask the CMs for their guidance and support for changing the site name and site blurbs.

Suggestions and constructive criticism are welcome.

## Related

- [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/709/88163)
- [How do we promote our site?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/474/88163)

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for making this change:

> 1. Removed *power users*.

I admit, I have expressed frustration with the closure of some questions. On occasion, you have expressed that the questions weren't fit for power users, and that's why they were closed. I felt frustrated by that, as I felt that this website is for all users of web applications. I was sure that the rest of the community felt similarly. It seemed to me that the moderators weren't listening. I got so frustrated that I had to take a break from visiting Web Apps at all for a month or two.

Today I eat humble pie and thank you for making this change in the wording. It seems to me you are only making it because of what the community said. Thank you for listening to the community on this.

Comment: that was very kind of you to post.  I am re-energized!

Comment: Thank you, @BlindSpots. I'm guessing you must feel that I'm sending mixed messages (with regard to my other posts and comments). I'm still frustrated, but I'm also glad that the moderators are willing to listen to the community on this point about the focus on power users. I know being a moderator is a difficult job.

Comment: you don't need to guess.  I'll tell you what I'm thinking  Are you aware that I created https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148310/blind-and-flimm to chat with you and have left you some messages there.  It is a great way to vent your frustrations when you don't want to post but want to rant.